# Themeing the Popup of the ShareActionProvider from ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, shareactionprovider

I want to theme the `ShareActionProvider` of the ActionBarSherlock. My problem is that I successfully customized the styles of the ActionBar but I cannot style the share popup which comes from the ActionBarSherlock.

[image: Share and Menu example]

In the Screenshot above you can see the share popup uses the default styles while a normal *more* popup is styled in that way I like.

I digged more thrue the source code and found in `ActivityChooserView` this method:

```
private IcsListPopupWindow getListPopupWindow() {
    if (mListPopupWindow == null) {
        mListPopupWindow = new IcsListPopupWindow(getContext());
        //...
```

Which is as far I know responsable for creating that Popup of the `ShareActionProvider`. As you can see above a new instance of `IcsListPopupWindow` is created. Here are the constructors of `IcsListPopupWindow`:

```
public IcsListPopupWindow(Context context) {
    this(context, null, R.attr.listPopupWindowStyle);
}

public IcsListPopupWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    mContext = context;
    mPopup = new PopupWindow(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    mPopup.setInputMethodMode(PopupWindow.INPUT_METHOD_NEEDED);
}
```

So far the attr `com.actionbarsherlock.R.attr.listPopupWindowStyle` used. While this attr is inserted the one and two parameter constructor of `IcsListPopupWindow` created a new `PopupWindow` with the attr `com.android.internal.R.attr.popupWindowStyle` which seems to be equal with `android.R.attr.popupWindowStyle`:

```
public PopupWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.popupWindowStyle);
}

public PopupWindow(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    mContext = context;
    mWindowManager = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    TypedArray a =
        context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.PopupWindow, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    mBackground = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.PopupWindow_popupBackground);

    // ...
```

There you can see that the background image is loaded from a style called `styleable.PopupWindow_popupBackground`. I tried to apply my style with this xml file:

```
<style name="Theme.MyStyle" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyStyle</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_mystyle</item>
    <item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyStyle</item>
    <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.MyStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_mystyle</item>
    <item name="android:divider">#081925</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.MyStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">#081925</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

**But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?**
By the way I would be really happy if someone could give me a good tutorial for styleable and the attr stuff I don't get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to override the popupBackground color by overriding this ABS style:

```
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow" parent="Widget">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">#333333</item>
</style>
```

Hopefully that can get you going.  And if you were able to solve it on your own, please share with the rest of us how you styled the rest of the attributes.
Cheers

Comment: It works! I used just instead of `Widget.Sherlock.Light.ListPopupWindow` only `Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow` for customizing the background I used this three properties: <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_my_style</item>
<item name="android:divider">#081925</item>
<item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>